# how to isolate and texture a certain area of a mesh

Tags: materials, node-editor

[image: monster]

hello so i sculpted this beautiful boy over here and i want to make the area around his eyes alot darker than the rest of his body,most of the textures are procedural so is there of doing it in only the node editor.[image: node editor]

thanks to moonboot for the answer
[image]

Comment: if you absolutely want to keep it procedural you could use Vertex Paint?

Comment: could you explain further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use any image texture you can do it with *Vertex Paint*:

- Switch to *Vertex Paint* mode, open the *Tool* panel, choose a black color, select the *Blend > Mix* mode, paint around the eyes. The vertex paint only uses the vertices, so its smoothness and precision will depend on your mesh density:

[image]

- As you can see it has created a *Vertex Colors* group:

[image]

- In your *Shade Editor*, create a *Input > Attribute* node. In the *Name* field, type the name of the vertex color group you've just created. Now you can use it as a factor in a *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Comment: Note that in 2.80 there is a "Vertex Color" node which lets you select directly the vertex color group rather than having to type the name. But you lose the "Fac" output which you can get with a "RGB to BW" node.

Comment: oh ok, I used 2.8 but you must be talking about a later version

Comment: Oh, right, might be 2.81 :) sorry